# VSCode jupyter intellisense in py file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying out VSCode for doing data analysis in python and I really like it.  My favorite part is the interactive mode since I can send code from a .py file line by line without having to split it into new cells.  However, I can't get the Jupyter intellisense to work in the .py editing window even though there is a running jupyter kernel that is being sent the code.

**Is there a way that the .py file editor can get the code completion from the jupyter intellisense?**

I'm currently also using the Python extension which gives the Microsoft language server.  While it's nice, it is not as good as the jupyter one since it doesn't seem to be able to tell, for instance, what columns are in a pandas dataframe object.

Comment: Do you mean that the code input box in the "Interactive" window cannot be automatically completed? Could you please provide us with examples or screenshots to minimize the reproduction of this problem and the effect you want?

Comment: No, I'm talking about when I'm modifying the .py file in its own editor, not when I'm inputting into the Interactive window.  

Here's the autocompletion I'm currently seeing: https://imgur.com/a/AmsNzjd and here is the Jupyter autocompletion I'd like to see in place: https://imgur.com/a/e0l7CMA.

Notice that the .ipynb one sees that x has an "a" column.

Comment: In the ".py" file, although we use "# %%" to separate the code to run separately, this is like the command "Run selection", it is still a whole python file, so it is just like in Jupyter Like "x.a" cannot be displayed in one of the cells, it cannot get the updated compilation result. The cell in the ".ipynb" file is independent, and it can recognize the updated compilation result. They can all identify the methods and classes that come with the module.